# How to add google authentication in headers with curl in php

Tags: php, authentication, curl, http-headers

I need to request an api with curl in PHP.
First of all I need to get a token access, and to get it I need to request to this url (with my "client_id") : https://testexellia.bitrix24.fr/oauth/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id=local.5d3c9f79b65439.23207420&redirect_uri=app_URL

It should answer me a new url with the token inside.
It works very well when I request with Chrome, but with curl I get this answer -> https://www.bitrix24.net/oauth/authorize/?user_lang=fr&client_id=b24.5d399107d0f2b9.16511658&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftestexellia.bitrix24.fr%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%2F%3Fauth_service_id%3DBitrix24Net%26oauth_proxy_params%3DcmVkaXJlY3RfdXJpPWFwcF9VUkwmY2xpZW50X2lkPWxvY2FsLjVkM2M5Zjc5YjY1NDM5LjIzMjA3NDIwJnJlc3BvbnNlX3R5cGU9Y29kZQ%253D%253D%26sessid%3Db6ded2712b7e66e4b34f05411eb2f4f1&scope=auth,profile&response_type=code&mode=page&state=site_id%3Ds1%26backurl%3D%252Foauth%252Fauthorize%252F%253Fcheck_key%253D7d6109a54034f59c406798d6a9667a9c%2526response_type%253Dcode%2526client_id%253Dlocal.5d3c9f79b65439.23207420%2526redirect_uri%253Dapp_URL%26mode%3Dpage

So the login page.

I know where is the problem, I'm already logged with Chrome (probably with cookies I guess) to the website, and obviously the curl request not.

I guess I need to add some headers informations to my request, like a password and login, but I'm logged to this website with my Google Account.

So is there a way to add Google informations in the curl's header ? I can't find how.

Here is the doc of the API, in case you need.

Edit : Here is the code.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://testexellia.bitrix24.fr/oauth/authorize/?response_type=code&client_id=local.5d3c9f79b65439.23207420&redirect_uri=app_URL&sessid=b6ded2712b7e66e4b34f05411eb2f4f1",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"Accept: */*",
"Authorization: Bearer 08493f5d003eabc0003e9b9e00000001f0f103a29e30c5356d8e8142404add6515e135",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
"Connection: keep-alive",
"Host: testexellia.bitrix24.fr",
"Postman-Token: 6de6ba41-b9fc-4541-98b0-c2f9d9b1ea7f,b36cd02a-87f8-4fb1-821c-54602a300bc5",
"User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.13.0",
"accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
"cache-control: no-cache",
"cookie: PHPSESSID=fOJKQhrXBNuNmrmIOXXg0YDlIeckdVfm; qmb=.; BITRIX_SM_SALE_UID=0"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
$content  = curl_exec($curl);
$redirectedUrl = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

curl_close($curl);


echo $redirectedUrl;
```

Thank you very much.

Benjamin.

Comment: where is your curl / php code?

Comment: I edited my post, it's my very first time here, sorry !